# "To this end" or "To that end"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, determiners, this-that

Is there a usage note for choosing between these two phrases? Nothing in Garner.  And I've seen it both ways.

***Example:***

> To that end, we propose the following compromise.

**or**

> To this end, we propose the following compromise.

Comment: It really makes no difference.

Comment: It's the same as the difference between `this` and `that`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this sentence, *end* does not mean *side*, it means *goal*. *To this end* means *In order to achieve this goal*.

Whether you say *in order to achieve this goal* or *in order to achieve that goal* makes *very* little difference, if any.

If your sentence was *to win, he has to run to this / that end of the trail*, there *is* a difference, with *this*, he has to start from the far side and come towards the speaker, whereas with *that* he runs away from the speaker to the far end of the trail.

Answer (score -2):

'To that end' sounds conversational.  'To the other end' may be apt.

Comment: "To the other end" would change the meaning completely.  It is not at all apt.